# Not able to hide a span with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

```
<span id='".$objResultFile["file_id"]."'>"
```

I am trying to hide the above span, with the help of jQuery, but cannot get it working.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
                        $(document).ready(function () {
                            $(".class").click(function () {
                                const get_ele_id = $(this).attr("id");
                                const get_file_name = $(this).data("fname");
                                $("input#" + get_ele_id).show().val(get_file_name);
                                $("span#" + get_ele_id).hide();
                             })
                            })
                  </script>
                  <?php
                            $strQueryFile = queryDB("*","tb_file", "user_id", $_SESSION['user_id']);
                            $objQueryFile = mysqli_query(connect_db(),$strQueryFile);
                            while ($objResultFile = mysqli_fetch_array($objQueryFile,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                                echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<td><input style='display: none' id='".$objResultFile["file_id"]."' type='text'><span id='".$objResultFile["file_id"]."'>".$objResultFile["file_name"]."</span></td>";
                                echo "<td>".$objResultFile["uploaded_on"]."</td>";
                                echo "<td><a href='delete_file.php?file_id=".$objResultFile["file_id"]."&file_name=".$objResultFile["file_name"]."' onClick=\"return confirm('ท่านต้องการลบไฟล์ ".$objResultFile["file_name"]."')\"><span data-feather='trash-2'></span></a></td>";
                                echo "<td><a href='#'  id='".$objResultFile["file_id"]."' class='class' data-fname='".$objResultFile["file_name"]."' data-fid='".$objResultFile["file_id"]."'><span id='1' data-feather='trash-2'></span></a></td>";
                                echo "</tr>";
                            }
                            mysqli_close(connect_db());
                  ?>
```

Comment: When writing jquery, always look at the *output HTML* not the php hieroglyphs.  2ndly, you have multiple elements with the same ID  `$("input#id")` `$("span#id")` which is not valid HTML.  Your 2nd `$("span#id")` is finding the first div with id and checking if it's a span, which it's not, so does nothing.  Try `$("span[id=" + get_ele_id + "]").hide();` or fix the multiple ID issue.

Comment: Thank you 
$("span[id=" + get_ele_id + "]").hide();
it work for me
but how should I fix ID problems?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing quotes, changing :

```
<span id='".$objResultFile["file_id"]."'>"
```

To :

```
<span id=".$objResultFile["file_id"].">"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
But i use <span class='".$objResultFile["file_id"]."'>"
```

and

```
$("span." + get_ele_id).hide();
```

it works

Comment: $("span[id=" + get_ele_id + "]").hide();
it works
I think duplicate ID